# How to fetch and change value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<form id="target" method="POST" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="item" id="txtEmail"   value='{"_id":"55a0af70b2a45442078b196d","count":1}'>
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value='true'>
<input type="submit">
```

I want to change the value of count dynamically using jquery.Any help is accepted.

Comment: When you want to change the value of count....On any event or on page redirect or what ? Please specify

Comment: No way this is not a duplicate of something - search before you post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following steps:

- Fetch value from text field
- Parse JSON and store in object
- Set new value to object
- Again set value to text as string

Consider following:

```
var textVal = $("#txtEmail").val();
var obj = JSON.parse(textVal);
obj.count = 2;//as you want
$("#txtEmail").val(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqpoeqg0/1/)

Comment: Almost close :-) beat you in 25 seconds

Comment: @xyz: This is not a race. But if it was, you would have won :)

Comment: @D4V1D: Its not a race. I was just knocked out by the identical code post at the same time :-)

Comment: @xyz you are knocked off because your answer doesn't say anything but a code block. which might be good but other one is better.

Comment: @Jai I agree. I saw that Manwal putting efforts, so, I counted on him :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  var val = $('#txtEmail').val();
  var valObj = JSON.parse(val);
  valObj.count = 100;//set anything you want
  $('#txtEmail').val(JSON.stringify(valObj));
});
```

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Good Luck :-)

Comment: @Manwal :thumbs_up: its a win-win for SO :-)